# listview items are appears at fixed left and right sides

Tags: java, android, css

inserted-right

[image]

inserted_left

[image]

I am sending a message to myself in the application as it should appear as send the message as green bubble then below received the message as left (blue bubble).

but in the above images, the messages are appearing in fixed place as
whenever I send the message, the send message appear upper right (green bubble)
and the received message as below (blue bubble)

Thanks in advance

### I want the out put as

```
              you2
```

you2

when I again send the message it should appear as

```
            you3
```

you3

```
           you4
```

you4

chatlistAdapter.java

```
public class chatList_AdapterClass extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<chatList_row> mArrayList;
ViewHolder mHolder=null;

public chatList_AdapterClass(Context context, ArrayList<chatList_row> arrayList) {
    mContext = context;
    mArrayList = arrayList;
}

public class ViewHolder{

    TextView mReceivedMessage;

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams mParams;


    ViewHolder(View v){
        mReceivedMessage=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.ChatListMessages);


    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mArrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return mArrayList.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View ConvertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row=ConvertView;
    if (row == null){

        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_list_row,parent,false);


        mHolder=new ViewHolder(row);
        mHolder.mParams=(LinearLayout.LayoutParams)mHolder.mReceivedMessage.getLayoutParams();
        row.setTag(mHolder);
    }else {

        mHolder=(ViewHolder)row.getTag();

    }

    mHolder.mReceivedMessage.setText(mArrayList.get(position).getMessageContent());

    boolean send=mArrayList.get(position).getTypeofMessage().equals("send");
    setChatRowAppearance(send,mHolder);

    return row;
}

public  void setChatRowAppearance(boolean send,ViewHolder mHolder){


    if (send){
        mHolder.mParams.gravity= Gravity.END;
        mHolder.mReceivedMessage.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        mHolder.mReceivedMessage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble2);

    }else {

        mHolder.mParams.gravity= Gravity.START;
        mHolder.mReceivedMessage.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        mHolder.mReceivedMessage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble1);


    }

}




}
```

Comment: check your arraylist . maybe in arraylist you are adding first all sendflag true and after that send flag false.

Comment: Yes,m passing two messages to same arraylist  and retrieving from every time it show all send one side and all received at other side how can I solve this ?